# Interfce with multiple generic types?

Tags: java, generics, interface

This Is my Interfce `BinaryHeterogenousHyperedge`:

```
public interface BinaryHeterogenousHyperedge
    <M extends Vertex<L>, L,T extends Vertex<E>, E>
extends Hyperedge
{
    public <T> List<Vertex> search(T centroid  ,List<M> allElemntsVertex);
}
```

The method search take two parameter :

- a centroid vertex of type `T` ( for example Tag Vertex)
- a list of Vertx of type `M` != `T` (for example Image Vertex)

and return a list of vertex of both type `T` and `M`

`TagsImagesHyperEdges` implements this interface:

```
public class TagImagesHyperedge
    implements BinaryHeterogenousHyperedge
                   <ImageVertex,Map<String, Instance> ,TagVertex,String>
{

@Override
public <T> List<Vertex> search(T centroid, List<ImageVertex> allElemntsVertex)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why is type `T` not inferred?

Comment: What do you mean with *Why type T is not inferred?*?

Comment: in the class  TagImagesHyperEdge 
type T must be replaced with TagVertex

Comment: Yes, it will be inferred, but you have a different `<T>` in `search` method.

Comment: @millimoose that should be an answer :).

Comment: yes yes 
I should delete <T> in search method 
thanks

Answer (score 5):

You're shadowing the T from the interface definition with the T in the method definition. **Never do this.** They're different, unrelated type parameters, there's no way for one to be inferred from another. Your method signature is basically a very confusing way of saying:

```
public List<Vertex> search(Object centroid, List<M> allElementsVertex);
```

A rule of thumb for Java: it *never makes sense* to use a method-level type parameter if it's only used once in the method signature. Method-level type parameters are useful for expressing a constraint *between* parameter types or the return type.